# How to refer images which are in liferay theme in portlet's css

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme

I have a liferay theme which has some application level images. Also a portlet with its own css.

How can I refer the images in theme from the portlet's css?

Comment: i guess you can use css for this. Set image in css class and apply that class where you want

Answer (score 2):

I believe that from the CSS files you can't (at least I couldn't think of a way to do this). However, if you expect it to be styled by the theme anyway, you can just have a `<div class="hasMyDesiredImage">` and make your theme(s) contain the theme-css to use the images from the theme itself:

e.g. your custom.css:

```
 .hasMyDesiredImage {
    background: url(../images/my/fancyImage.png);
 }
```

If you want to address a theme-based image from a portlet itself (where the code is dynamically processed) you can use [`themeDisplay.getPathThemeImages()`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay.html#getPathThemeImages%28%29):

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a custom theme, then the impages/CSS/JS in theme can be referenced directly using the reference path.

For ex: if Theme project which is in webapps is sample-theme, then you can give path like /sample-theme/images/filename.png